# How to parameterise method name in TestNG xml file?

Tags: java, selenium, testing, cucumber, testng

Below is the testng.xml code. here I have test name Test1 and I want to include all the scenarios starting with regression tag (tag is present in cucumber feature file).

### I want to parameterise "regression.*" value and want to pass as an argument at run time (Runas testng).

```
<test name="Test1">
  <groups>
    <run>
      <include name="regression.*"/>
    </run>
  </groups>
```

---

Can somebody help me with this scenario.

Thanks in advance.....

Comment: <suite name="My suite">
  <parameter name="first-name"  value="Cedric"/>
  <test name="Simple example">


referring https://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#parameters

Comment: Can you provided details about how you are using cucumber with testng and your feature file sample. For example, If you are using [BDDTestFactory2](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/latest/bdd-configuration.html#running-tests-with-specific-groups) and you have tags like `@regression` in feature file you can have `<include name="regression"/>`

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to build the dynamic ability to pick and choose a group at runtime using a beanshell as a method selector.

Here's a sample beanshell powered suite xml. In the below sample, we are making use of a JVM argument `-DgroupToRun` to pass in the name of the groups which we want to be executed.

For more details on how to work with beanshells in TestNG take a look at

- The official documentation [here](https://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#beanshell)
- my blog post [here](https://rationaleemotions.com/beanshell_in_testng/)

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Suite" parallel="false">
    <test name="Test">
        <method-selectors>
            <method-selector>
                <script language="beanshell">
                <![CDATA[
                    whatGroup = System.getProperty("groupToRun");
                    groups.containsKey(whatGroup);
                ]]>
                </script>
            </method-selector>
        </method-selectors>
        <classes>
            <class name="organized.chaos.GroupsPlayGround" />
        </classes>
    </test> <!-- Test -->
</suite> <!-- Suite -->
```